# Back up Windows 10 and Ubuntu partions from Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, backup

I'm a novice playing with Dual Boot. My PC is old and getting slow in W10 and I found it is operating like a new PC in Ubuntu. So I am using Ubuntu more and more. I'd like to give Ubuntu a larger partition and Windows less.

However I don't want to leave W10 completely.  So I'd like to back up my PC (all partitions) and then resize partitions to give Ubuntu more space. However all my previous backups were done in Macrium Reflect.

Is there a way I can back up all partitions including W10 in Ubuntu Backups? Or do I need to go back into Macrium to backup before I downzize my Windows partitions?

Comment: Macrium Reflect is what I use. I boot it from Windows or a USB flash drive.

Answer (score 2):

You're smart!  Taking a full system backup of everything is fairly easy using [CloneZilla Live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) as it saves only the allocated space of sparse files and compresses everything.

- Follow the instructions on how to download it and set it up on a USB stick [here](https://clonezilla.org/liveusb.php#linux-setup)
- Boot from USB stick (firmware dependent: check your BIOS / UEFI manual)
- Take `device-image`:
  [image: CloneZilla Device-Image]
- Take whichever you want to use to back up to (`local-dev` is a local USB HD)
  [image: CloneZilla Image save options]
- Then `save-disk` and check all your local disks except the external HDD you're going to back up to.
- Take default options and let it run.

#### As you're saving disks, it will save all partitions, including W10, Ubuntu and whatever else you've got.